# datepicker plugin not displaying selected value in another div

Tags: jquery, html, datepicker

I am using `airdatepicker.js` for my date-picker. It's a very straight forward date-picker just like JQuery date-picker.

I am trying to display the selected date in another div. (The value of the selected date.)

Here is my date-picker:

```
<div class="col-12 col-md-4">
     <span>Date of Request*</span>
     <input type="text" name="request-date" id="request-date" placeholder="Select a Date" class="input-type-date datepicker-here" data-language="en" onblur="if (this.placeholder == '') {this.placeholder = 'Select a Date';}" onfocus="if (this.placeholder == 'Select a Date') {this.placeholder = '';}">
</div>
```

I am trying to append the value of the selected date from the datepicker to this div:

```
<div class="col-12 col-md-5 spacing">
     <h5><strong>Date of Request</strong></h5><div id="input7"></div>
</div>
```

with this JQuery:

```
$('#request-date').keyup(function() {
    $('#input7').text($(this).val());
});
```

I don't know why but it is not working. I am thinking it might be because the value field might be empty.

But I don't know why it would be empty.

Any idea how to resolve this issue?

Comment: why do you think it should be `.keyup(...)` event? it's more likely you need to read value on `.blur(...)` or look into the API of the lib you use.

Comment: @VitaliiChmovzh I did it on a click event too. I am just trying different events to see if any of them work.

Answer (score 0):

why not :

```
$( "#request-date" ).change(function() {
    console.log("value = " + $(this).val()); //just to check val( )
    $('#input7').html($(this).val());
});
```

or use the airdatepicker events : http://t1m0n.name/air-datepicker/docs/#events

eg:

```
var eventDates = [1, 10, 12, 22],
$picker = $('#request-date'),
$content = $('#input7'),
sentences = [ … ];

$picker.datepicker({
language: 'en',
onRenderCell: function (date, cellType) {
    var currentDate = date.getDate();
    // Add extra element, if `eventDates` contains `currentDate`
    if (cellType == 'day' && eventDates.indexOf(currentDate) != -1) {
        return {
            html: currentDate + '<span class="dp-note"></span>'
        }
    }
},
onSelect: function onSelect(fd, date) {
    var title = '', content = ''
    // If date with event is selected, show it
    if (date && eventDates.indexOf(date.getDate()) != -1) {
        title = fd;
        content = sentences[Math.floor(Math.random() * eventDates.length)];
    }
    $('strong', $content).html(title)
    $('p', $content).html(content)
}
```

})

Comment: Seems like the value is not changing. So that is the problem. It is not capturing the value after selected.

Comment: use the native airdatepicker event then : http://t1m0n.name/air-datepicker/docs/#events